# fgets() not terminating on <Enter>

Tags: c, eclipse, user-input, fgets

I am developing a console application on Raspberry (Linux). I want to query the user, with the option of just hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to mean a default value.

The function `fgets` is meant to perform that, and should return a "\n" string in that case. I checked that it is the case on a PC (Windows).

But on the Raspberry, the function just does not exit, it merely performs a newline on screen. For the function to exit, I must enter at least one printing key.

Has anybody an explanation? How can I work around this?

---

**Update:** this occurs when executing under Eclipse. After checking, only on Rapsberry, not PC Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post a Minimal Reproducible Example?

Comment: @chqrlie: `char s[10]; fgets(s, 10, stdin);` But that must run on Raspberry.

Comment: How do you communicate with the RPi? Do you connect through SSH? Using serial terminal? Something else? How is the shell or terminal configured? Perhaps it's an `\r\n` versus `\n` issue?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: working straight on the Pi, USB keyboard. But why should Enter fail as the first keystroke and not after printing characters ?

Comment: The Pi toolkit does not exactly implement a conforming C environment. This may be one more quirk.

Comment: It shouldn't, which is why I'm leaning toward a configuration problem (shell or terminal configured in an "odd" way).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: this is an "off-the-shelf" distribution. Anyway, executing under Eclipe. I will try on a bare console.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a comment by @Someprogrammerdude, I checked that this behavior only occurs when running under Eclipe. Running on a standard console works as expected.

An explanation is still welcome, but not so "pressing".

Comment: Interesting. I will add an "Eclipse" tag to the question so that future users with the same issue can find this.

Comment: Eclipse, as many other IDEs, uses pipes or similar features to emulate a terminal. This could work more or less...